# $x \mathcal{o}\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right) =\mathcal{o}\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right) $?

Tags: taylor-expansion

Is this correct:

$$x \mathcal{o}\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right) = \mathcal{o}\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$

or the expression $x \mathcal{o}\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$ cannot be simplified?

Here $\mathcal{o}(\cdot)$ stands for little $\mathcal{o}$ of $\ \cdot$.

Comment: $$
\left| {xo\left( {\frac{1}{{x^3 }}} \right)} \right| \le \left| {x\varepsilon \frac{1}{{x^3 }}} \right| = \varepsilon \left| {\frac{1}{{x^2 }}} \right|.
$$

Comment: So if I don't want to introduce a new variable ($\varepsilon$) would you suggest to leave it as it is?

Comment: I indicated you how to show that $$
xo\left( {\frac{1}{{x^3 }}} \right) = o\left( {\frac{1}{{x^2 }}} \right).
$$

Answer (score 2):

$f(x) = o\left(\dfrac{1}{x^2} \right)$ if $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \ x^2f(x) = 0.$

Define $g(x) = \dfrac{1}{x}f(x)$, so $g(x) = \dfrac{1}{x}o\left(\dfrac{1}{x^2}\right)$, but
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \ x^3g(x) =\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \ x^2f(x) = 0$$ so $g(x) = o\left(\dfrac{1}{x^3}\right)$.

Comment: This is very hard to read; it will be easier if you break it up into a few sentences on separate lines. You can also use `$\lim$` instead of `$lim$` for better typesetting. (Without the backslash, `$lim$` is interpreted as the product $l \cdot i \cdot m$.)

Comment: Thank you for the advice.